# Can Eclipse / Netbeans run "inline" PHP / Perl in PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, database, eclipse, postgresql, netbeans

I searched StackOverflow, and the rest of the web, but could not find answers for any of these questions.

My questions are - Can Eclipse or Netbeans run "inline" code? Basically, if I am writing code in PostgreSQL, can I then use some sort of symbol to indicate that the next bit of code will be PHP, and then use some sort of end symbol to indicate the end of the PHP, and that the rest of the code will be PostgreSQL? Can Perl or other languages be "embedded" into code like this too? Does this only hold true for "scripting" or "markup" languages? If you ran this code, would it successfully compile both the postgreSQL and PHP code? Could this be run through the IDE on a Windows system? If anyone has a link about, or a screenshot of, any of this, that they could provide, it would be greatly appreciated.

On a similar note, does Netbeans or Eclipse have native syntax-checking or auto-completion for PostgreSQL? Or is the only option for these things the Toadext plugin?

Thank you so much!

Comment: What do you mean by "PostgreSQL code"?

Comment: I mean the Postgres query language. I'm referring to writing in the Postgres query language, then PHP, then Postgres query language, all in the same line, or same document, - and then having the IDE run it.

Comment: It pays to be explicit, since most of these languages have interfaces to call *out* to PostgreSQL as an external data source, as well as being available to write PostgreSQL functions as a PL. Beyond that, there is sometimes more than one implementation of a given language available as a PL, so it is best to name the specific PL installed and give version numbers. I think Craig's probably got it sorted out in his answer, but if he misunderstood, or you post any similar questions, please be explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Inline language features are specific to particular languages, and nothing to do with your IDE.

For example, PHP supports in-line blocks of HTML and JavaScript because the PHP interpreter and language are written to handle that. Similarly, PostgreSQL's procedural languages accept various languages inside their `$$ $$` quoted blocks because they're explicitly designed to; `$$` quoted blocks are just special cases of string literals anyway.

With proper support NetBeans could probably recognise and check, say, PL/PHP within `$$` quoted procedure blocks in PostgreSQL SQL code. I doubt anybody's implemented such a feature, though, and *as far as I know* NetBeans doesn't support any kind of "magic comment" you can use to tell it what language a block is in.

Inline blocks of code aren't concept that generalizes across all languages. You generally need to either keep the different languages' code in different files, or include one in the other as string literals. That's very common for the case of embedding SQL in another language, where you often keep SQL code in string literals:

```
String someSQL = "SELECT ...."
```

Of course, NetBeans sees that as a string, not as SQL, so it usually won't type check it for you. How could it? It doesn't know if that's a complete SQL statement, a fragment you intend to glue together with others using string concatenation, or something that just happens to *look* like SQL.

Eclipse can do some SQL syntax checking in-line with Java code in some cases, but usually you're on your own. If you want syntax checking and highlighting of your SQL, keep it in a separate file from your main code.

Comment: Thank you very much, for taking the time to make such an informative response!